# Scala plugin in Sonar

Tags: scala, sonarqube

I have seen that a plugin dedicated to Scala is under development (http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE45/Scala+Plugin).

Would someone be able to tell me when the development of this plugin will be completed and when it could be available through the SonarQube Update Center ?

I also found an other plugin (https://github.com/RadoBuransky/sonar-scoverage-plugin).
Do you plan to propose it in the SonarQube Update Center ?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think this question is actually suitable for stackoverflow. Please reach out the google groups for such kind of questions :  sonarqube@googlegroups.com which is far more suitable for discussion. 
To answer your question : mentioned plugin was an initiative from community which never made it to release stage. There are actually no defined plan to support scala on SonarSource side at time of writing.

Answer (score 9):

There is an official SonarSource Scala plugin. The documentation is here:
https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/languages/scala/

---

EDIT 03 Aug 2018

You could use [mwz/sonar-scala](https://github.com/mwz/sonar-scala) plugin. I see it is up-to-date.

---

The page http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE45/Scala+Plugin is very old and outdated.

There is no any official Scala plugin and probably will not be implemented in the near future.

From mailing list:

[Where is the official Sonar Scala plugin?](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/sonarqube/MkcW9tFG8UY/discussion) (07/Jul/2015)

> [Freddy Mallet](https://stackexchange.com/users/561076): there isn't any official SonarQube Scala plugin

[Source Code of Scala Plugin?](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/sonarqube/Cr_G1gtLBiw/discussion) (28/Aug/2015)

> [Dinesh Bolkensteyn](https://stackexchange.com/users/108394): it has been removed due to the lack of activity. [...] you can find the latest master here: https://github.com/hgomez-sonarsource/sonar-scala

Answer (score 0):

Looks like somebody else stepped up to fill the void.   Check out this [plugin](https://github.com/Sagacify/sonar-scala).